# How to pass dict of dicts to pytest

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, automated-tests, pytest

**testdata** object holds credentials for various companies. I would like pass this object to pytest test function. In this case, 2 tests needs to be run (one each for Company 1 and  2).

```
testdata = {
    "Company1": {
        "username": "user1",
        "password": "pass!"
    }, "Company2": {
        "username": "user2",
        "password": "pass!"
    }
}
```

Here is the test function

```
def test_login():
    # call login function by passing username and password
    # Returns True if Success else False
    assert login()
```

I tried *@pytest.mark.parametrize* but couldn't figure out how to pass dicts.

Any pointers on how to solve this would be really helpful.

Answer (score 3):

This is how you would *@pytest.mark.parametrize* to pass dicts and other value types.

```
import pytest


@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "data, value",
    [
        ({"Company1": {"username": "user1", "password": "pass!"},
         "Company2": {"username": "user2", "password": "pass!"}}, "some value")
    ]
)
def test_example(data, value):
    assert isinstance(data, dict)
    assert value == "some value"
```

However, if you wanted to split this dictionary in two to run as a separate tests, you'd want to do something like this:

```
import pytest


@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "data, value",
    [
        ({"username": "user1", "password": "pass!"}, "some value"),
        ({"username": "user2", "password": "pass!"}, "some value")
    ]
)
def test_example(data, value):
    assert isinstance(data, dict)
    assert value == "some value"
```

Answer (score 0):

it's not a good pratice when you creates asserts for instances.. you might assert keys/values.

You can use fixture too

Comment: Are you saying doing `assert dict1 == dict2` isn't good practice? Why not?

Comment: No that's good.. is not good when you try to assert instances types. =)